# What is the title and author of a book about a research scientist fending off aliens on a world of large plants?

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

A research scientist on a newly discovered planet inhabited by only animals and strange large plants discovers aliens have landed on the forest world. She hides out among the plants and sabotages the aliens’ plan for an invasion of the Earth.

***I read this novel sometime in the nineteen-seventies, so that the one scene in the book that I can remember in detail is when the scientist was traveling to her established outpost to set off a warning system. She was nearly seen by an alien scout ship above, so she hid herself in a large bulbous plant.

When she crawled into the bulb of the plant, it closed over her like it did to the flying "birds" she had observed on the world.  She was dusted by pollen during her stay in the soft cushioned inside of the plant where she drank collected rain water purified by the plant, and slept for a few hours. To get out of the plant, she rubbed the sides of the bulb like she had seen the birds do on the outside with their beaks, and it opened up, clearing the way for her to quickly travel by the vines of the plants through the forest.  Camouflaged, she arrived at her outpost unseen, but the aliens had set up camp … and they were looking for her.

Comment: Off to a good start, but we could use some more details. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds vaguely like

> [The Demon Breed](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2121)

by James H. Schmitz

It does feature a research scientist in a forested area fighting off aliens intent on invading Earth.
However the forested area is on a floating island, and much of the action takes place underwater.

It also features giant mutated otters who can talk.

Comment: That's not very likely.  (a) Nandy-Cline is not newly discovered, there is a long-established human civilization on it. (b) Nandy-Cline is a water world, not  forest world, though since most of the action takes place in vegetation on a floating island, that may not be a conclusive objection.(c) The alien invasion is of the Federation of the Hub, not of Earth. 

Two big aspects of Demon Breed to consider: The mutated otters who work with the woman, and the idea of the Tuvalas -- the aliens believe that there are human supermen, and the woman successfully convinces them that she is one.

Comment: Sounds great, but the major action takes place above the water, and I don't remember any giant otters. Thanks for the lead to another interesting book though. 

I am adding more detail to my question.

Comment: The added detail certainly is a very good fit to The Demon Breed. (I can't include a quote in a comment.)  Does "Nile Etland" ring a bell? -- it's the biologist's name in The Demon Breed.  (BTW, The Demon Breed was also titled "The Tuvela".)

Comment: Ok. I looked up Demon Breed and looked at an old cover. That is it! I will have to read it again. Thank you so much for the information.

Comment: BTW, I named my first child, a girl, after the main character because I was so impressed by the strong female character. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I like a lot of Schmitz, but I really think that this may be his best. And Nile Etland is a fantastic character.

Comment: @Dee If you are satisfied with the answer, please "accept" it by clicking on the check mark next to it.